# passing JSON array from JavaScript to java and convert JSON array to java array

Tags: java, javascript, android, arrays, json

In my application, I need to pass JSON array to java then convert that array to java array using java as a language. Here is the code.

**JavaScript**

```
  function arraytofile(rans)
  {
      myData.push(rans); // rans is the random number
      var arr = JSON.stringify(myData);// converting to json array
      android.arraytofile(arr); // passing to java
  }
```

**Java**

```
  public void arraytofile(String newData) throws JSONException {
      Log.d(TAG, "MainActivity.setData()");
      System.out.println(newData);
  }
```

`newData` is printing data as `[[2],[3],[4]]...` I want in regular java array. How I can achieve this?

Comment: Use a JSON parser library like Jackson or Gson. This is not hard to check on the net using your favorite SEO.

Comment: http://www.json.org/java/

Comment: @MohammadAdil no, please no. Anything is better as a JSON library for Java than org.json. Please.

Comment: @fge  OMG.. is there anything wrong with that ? i personally use that in my project.

Comment: How to implement? I am learning java. So takes time to understand

Comment: @MohammadAdil this library is very limited to navigate JSON texts, has poor support for serialization and deserialization, among others; Jackson or Gson are much better choices

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Google gson` . An excellent `Java` library to work with `JSON`.

Find it here: https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Using gson library classes you can do something like this:

```
    // I took a small sample of your sample json
    String json = "[[2],[3],[4]]";
    JsonElement je = new JsonParser().parse(json);
    JsonArray jsonArray = je.getAsJsonArray();
    // I'm assuming your values are in String, you can change this if not
    List<String> javaArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(JsonElement jsonElement : jsonArray) {
        JsonArray individualArray = jsonElement.getAsJsonArray();
        JsonElement value = individualArray.get(0);
        // Again, I'm assuming your values are in String
        javaArray.add(value.getAsString());
    }
```

Now you have your json as Java `List<String>`. That's basically as array.

If you know exact number of results, you can surely define an array of fix size and then assign values to it.

If you know `Java`, than you already know how to go from here.

I hope this helps.